i use video tag but thumbnail is not showing on Safari browser in mobile view
i want to show my video thumbnail on safari browser in mobile view but in other browser like chrome , Firefox etc running absolutely fine in web view or mobile view
here is my code in react js
{isLoading ? (
                <Shimmer width={400} height={400} />
              ) : (
                <>
                  {isSafari ? (
                 
                    <video>
                      <source
                       //
                        src={parseUrlFromModel(data)}
                       width={150}
                        onLoadedMetadata={handleLoadedMetadata}
                        muted={isMuted}
                        style={{
                          position: 'absolute',
                          top: 0,
                          left: 0,
                          objectFit: 'fix',
                        }}
                      />
                    </video>
                  ) : (
                 
                    <video
                      ref={playerRef}
                      src={parseUrlFromModel(data)}
                      width='100%'
                      height='100%'
                      onLoadedMetadata={handleLoadedMetadata}
                      muted={isMuted}
                      style={{
                        position: 'absolute',
                        top: 0,
                        left: 0,
                        objectFit: 'cover',
                      }}
                    />
                  )}
                </>
           
              )}


